# Check if SQS exists in AWS using .NET

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm able to successfully send messages to a queue in .NET using the AmazonSQSClient clientin the AWSSDK.SQS package.

How can I check to see whether a specific queue exists, and if it doesn't create it?

Comment: Have you tried to just create it again?  In Java that works just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd need to run a check using the `AmazonSQSClient.GetQueueUrl (string)` method, where the string is the queue name.  If the queue doesn't exist, it throws `QueueDoesNotExistException`.  For you to do what you want, you'd need to catch the exception, and then create the queue using that name.

This is all listed in the SQS .Net Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SQS/NSQS.html)

Comment: So there's no dedicated light-weigh API to check if a specific queue exists? I'd rather not manage exceptions like that as it's going to be an action I'll need to perform continually and at a high rate. I'll have to look into a different work around. Thanks for the information.

Comment: You should not need to check whether a queue exists, "continually and at a high rate." It sounds as if you have design assumptions that need to be re-evaluated.  If a queue doesn't exist, there are no messages in it, no consumers listening to it, and no producers writing to it.