# How to test an AWS SQS connection?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, cloud, messaging, amazon-sqs

I've got a C# application which uses AWS SQS. I'm using SQS inside a wrapper/adapter component to hide away the messy details, and this component has an initialization hook that I'd like to fill in to make sure that the connection is valid. I don't see anything in the API for this besides sending a message. I'd like to verify that the credentials are valid and that the queue exists at the specified URL at application startup, if possible, and without sending a message.

I can think of some hacky ways to possibly do this (for instance, try sending an invalid message, such as one over the size limit) but would rather not go that route. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if SQS exists in AWS using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532235/check-if-sqs-exists-in-aws-using-net)

Comment: FYI, you can use this generic "ping" URL for testing if a server can even communicate with Amazon SQS for environments where firewall rules may need to be added. This does not test credentials but still ensures SQS is reachable. You will just need to adjust the URL for the particular AWS region the app is using. If successful, it should return an HTTP 200 OK with a plain text response body of "healthy". https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ping

Answer (score 3):

Verifying queue existence is a good use case for [GetQueueUrl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueUrl.html); it'll return either the queue url if it exists, or an error if it doesn't.